# Flutter TextField change focused background color

Tags: flutter

I would like to set different fill colors when TextField focused, but I tried many ways that didn't work unless use FocusNode.

Does TextField support this feature without FocusNode?

my code:

```dart
    final BorderRadius radius = BorderRadius.circular(16.0);
    final OutlineInputBorder errorBorder = OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: const BorderSide(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: 2.0,
      ),
      borderRadius: radius,
    );

    return TextFormField(
        autofocus: false,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.grey,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
            borderRadius: radius,
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: const BorderSide(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: 2.0,
            ),
            borderRadius: radius,
          ),
          focusedErrorBorder: errorBorder,
          errorBorder: errorBorder,
        ),
        onChanged: (String? v) {
          
        },
        validator: (String? v) {
          if (v != null && v.length > 3) {
            return '';
          }
          
          return null;
        },
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
      );
```

Comment: have you tried focusBorder or border or enabled border?

Comment: Yes, the border color worked, and I also set `filled` to true, `fillColor` worked as well.

Comment: Can you add your code snippet

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have updated my code snippet.